# Unable to connect to AWS RDS server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to AWS RDS database using pgAdmin4, I encounter and error:

```
Unable to connect to server:
could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "database-1.xxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (xx.xxx.xxx.xx) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried to Allow Public Accessibility and InBound Rules from my IP. But I am still getting the error? What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same error but for the MySQL database in rds. What I did was, I
went to http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ and checked the IP shown. I copied that IP and created a new security group by adding two rules, one is your standard all traffic rule, and the second is the one with custom IP which you just copied. Then went to rds and changed VPC security grp to both default and the one I just created. Do this and try to connect again. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For a quick test, try opening your inbound rule like this. If it works, then you know the issue is your IP address in your inbound rule:

[image]

Once you set this- can you connect?

Comment: No, I couldn't connect after setting 0.0.0.0/0 and All Traffic. In cmd, `telnet myipaddress port` , I could not connect to RDS.

Comment: So you have it set to public access and have this open rule set and it still fails? That is weird. And you have the correct user/password too right?

Comment: I believe I used a correct username and password.

Comment: Can you try another tool - like MySQL workbench (assuming its MySQL for example)

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Postgres.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam if want to try a different tool, you can try Dbeaver as well

Answer (score 0):

I've met the similar problem, and the solution consists on creating a database with the new database VPC security group, naming is independent. An option "Publicly accessible" should be set as "Yes": [VPC security group identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUYoc.png)

You should also check Inbound rules of the created VPC security group to define your IP address or the 0.0.0.0/0 value as a Source